# Upload Image and Get Image URL - PHP / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

How can I have an upload button that opens the upload file screen and lets the user choose an image, then when the user has chosen the image, I get a shortened link to that image so I can do stuff with it?

Basically, I need an upload file system but I mostly need the image URL because I will be saving it and I think it will be easier to display it to the user in preview mode.

Answer (score 1):

This jquery plugin does what you need, it has multiple back-end options PHP is the default
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/